# Evaluating condition continues when condition is not met

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

In a WebBrowser control in a Visual Studio Form this code works fine:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText =
    "<html><body>Search in Google:<br/>" &
    "<form method='get' action='http://www.google.com/search'>" &
    "<input type='text' name='as_q'/><br/>" &
    "<input type='submit' value='Search'/>" &
    "</form></body></html>"

End Sub
```

When I add the following code to Validating an HTML form through the WebBrowser Document property get this error message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating

    Dim document = WebBrowser1.Document
    If document IsNot Nothing And
    document.All("as_q") IsNot Nothing And
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(
    document.All("as_q").GetAttribute("value")) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        MsgBox("Please enter a search term.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Zagger. This and other examples work !!!!. Sorry.. Zaggler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all your `And` to `AndAlso`... As of right now you are still trying to evaluate the logic.

When you use the `AndAlso` **it will short circuit** and jump out when a condition is not met.